# bootstrap-datepicker input needs focus-out focus-in to re-initialize

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

When I have a (bootstrap eternicode) datepicker open and click and drag the browser's scrollbar, the datepicker is naturally losing focus and thus hiding.

But I am not able to view the datepicker directly again. I need to first click on another element, before going back to the date-pickers input in order to make it visible again.

How can I prevent this from happening?